# Python Permutations in which each position is limited

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation, combinatorics

I'm trying to learn how I can generate all permutations of a string, but each position is limited - so it's like permutations of permutations.

I need strings of length 8 where position 1 can be 'A', 'G' or 'T', for example, but position 3 can only be 'A', and so on.

Like so:

```
 Pos:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

       A A A     A   A
       G G   G G G G G
       T T           T
```

One example output being `'AGAGGGGT'`

By my calculation, this should yield 3*3*1*1*1*2*1*3 = 54 different variants

I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
import itertools

print list(itertools.permutations([['A','G','T']['A','G','T']['A']['G']['G']['A','G']['G']['A','G','T']], 8))
```

I assume that it would be something along those lines however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [83]: import itertools as IT

In [93]: IT.product('AGT', 'AGT', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'AG', 'G', 'AGT')
Out[93]: <itertools.product at 0xba654b4>

In [94]: len(list(IT.product('AGT', 'AGT', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'AG', 'G', 'AGT')))
Out[94]: 54
```

`IT.product` returns an iterator of tuples. To convert the tuples to strings, you could use `''.join` in a list comprehension:

```
In [96]: [''.join(item) for item in IT.product('AGT', 'AGT', 'A', 'G', 'G', 'AG', 'G', 'AGT')]
```

Comment: That gives me a list of tuples - how would I make it a list of lists or a list of strings?